# Can't install XNA4.0

Tags: windows-7, installation, xna

I failed to install XNA 4.0. It messages the bootstrapper.exe when installing Microsoft Games for Windows Live Redistributable. Then I installed the latest version of Microsoft Games for Windows and tried again, but it still failed. I have installed VS2010 and my OS is Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Which link did you download XNA 4.0 from?

Comment: Please provide the exact link.

Comment: @Mathias Here is the link: microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23714

Comment: Are there any details showing up such as an error-message, and error-code, an error-report or anything like it?

Comment: @Mathias It shows error-message of "bootstrapper.exe stops work" and then the install program crashes

Comment: Can you check out which version of Windows Installer you have?

Comment: @Mathias Mine is Windows (R) Installer. V 5.0.7601.17514

Comment: @Mathias I have solved this problem, I extracted all files from install program and install them manually, thanks

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by extracting all files from the installation program and installing them manually. You can extract the files by inputting the following in a Command Prompt:

```
your-install-program /x
```